# Mongoose query in an Object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Question, I got a schema using mongoose which created an Object. I don't know how to query the `author id` which will return the list of the object under the `author Id`

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bookedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   origin: String,
   destination: String,
   author: { id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}, username: String},
   Date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Booked", bookedSchema);
```

On my route I have query `find({})` i want to query the author id instead of `{}` and it will return the list of object under the author ID. i tried the `findById(author:{id:req.user._id})` but it returned null answer. any ideas how to do that. Thank You!

```
router.get('/myAccount', function(req, res){
    Booked.find({}).exec(function(err, booked){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            // res.redirect('back');
        }else{
            console.log(booked)
            res.render('accounts/myAccount', {booking:booked});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use .populate() for refered documents to populate them.
change this:

```
Booked.find({}).exec(function(err, booked)
```

to:

```
Booked.find({}).populate('author').exec(function(err, booked)
```

or if you need to find a document by the refered author id you can use this:

```
Booked.find({}).populate({
  path: 'author',
  match: { id: { $eq: req.user._id }}
}).exec(function(err, booked)
```

Comment: Hi Arootin, thanks for the reply i used the `populate("author")` but i got an error ` Cast to ObjectId failed for value "admin" at path "_id" for model Booked`

Comment: anyway, another case is possible to query the object like `Booked.find({}).exec(function(err, booked)` i want to parse the `booked.origin`? I tried the `console.log(booked.origin)` but it gives `undefined`

Comment: I think this will solve that problem:
```path: 'author.id'```